# :gt() selector, index defined for a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying using the selector :gt() of jquery.It works when I put a number, for example :gt(3). I have a  numeric variable and want pass it for the selector,like:

```
var x = 9;
$("tr:gt(x)").hide();
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Use `$("tr:gt(" + x + ")").hide();`

Comment: Sometimes it isn't necessary to downvote question imho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string concatenation:

```
$('tr:gt(' + x + ')').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation as follows:

```
var x = 9;
$("tr:gt(" + x + ")").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `x` is a variable, it can't be a string.

```
$("tr:gt(" + x + ")").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var x = 9;
$("tr:gt("+x+")").hide();
```

Comment: I guess this is an answer the question, but traditionally, answering a question with a question looks weird, like you're not sure it works.

Comment: You're right, but I wrote it more as an expression than a real question. Sorry if it's misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You have to concatenate variable using `+` signs instead of putting it as string.

```
$("tr:gt(" + x + ")").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) [instead of :gt()](http://jsperf.com/jquery-gt-slice)

```
var x = 9;
$("tr").slice(x+1).hide();
```